# Custom message for BoundField in gridview in HTML markup

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview

I have a BoundField in my gridview. Some of these BoundField are empty if there is no data in the datasource. For such type of fields I want to show N/A, but from the HTML markup only. Is there any way to do so???

This is the code for my grid view which has empty values and for what I want to show N/A

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="POCreatedDate" HeaderText="Created On" DataFormatString=" {0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                    HtmlEncode="false"  SortExpression="POCreatedDate"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="PODueDate" HeaderText="Due Date"   DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                 HtmlEncode="false"  SortExpression="PODueDate"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NullDisplayText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.nulldisplaytext%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is all you need :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="POCreatedDate" HeaderText="Created On" 
  DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false"  
  SortExpression="POCreatedDate"
  NullDisplayText="N/A" />
```